# Filter condition not correctly applied to Clustered Columnstore index

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database, columnstore

Using the below example, the predicates are the same, however the top statement (correctly) returns 0 rows, the bottom statement returns 1 - even though the predicates do NOT match:

```
declare @barcode nchar(22)=N'RECB012ZUKI449M1VBJZ'  
declare @tableId int = null
declare @total decimal(10, 2) = 5.17

SELECT 1
FROM
    [dbo].[transaction] WITH (INDEX([IX_Transaction_TransactionID_PaymentStatus_DeviceID_DateTime_All]))
WHERE
    Barcode = @barcode
    AND StatusID = 1
    AND TableID = @tableID
    AND @total <= Total

SELECT 1
FROM
    [dbo].[transaction] 
WHERE
    Barcode = @barcode
    AND StatusID = 1
    AND TableID = @tableID
    AND @total <= Total
```

Why could this be happening?

Further info:

- The Non Clustered Index in the top statement is NOT filtered
- CheckDB returns 0 issues
- Server Version: `Microsoft SQL Azure (RTM) - 12.0.2000.8   Dec 19 2018 08:43:17   Copyright (C) 2018 Microsoft Corporation`

Paste the Plan link:

https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=S1w_rU68E

Further Info:

Have ran `dbcc checktable ([transaction]) with all_errormsgs, extended_logical_checks, data_purity` which indicates no issues.

I can reliably reproduce the issue against this table when restoring a backup of this database.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90722/discussion-on-question-by-uberzen1-filter-condition-not-correctly-applied-to-clu).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This bug does not require dropping or renaming columns.

You will also see the same behaviour for `statusId = 100` which was never present in any version of the column.

#### Requirements

- A clustered columnstore
- Nonclustered b-tree index
- A plan that performs a lookup on the columnstore with

  - Target row(s) in **delta store**
  - A pushed non-SARG predicate
  - A comparison with NULL using an equality test

#### Example

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dbo.Example;
GO
CREATE TABLE dbo.Example
(
    c1 integer NOT NULL,
    c2 integer NULL,

    INDEX CCS CLUSTERED COLUMNSTORE,
    INDEX IX NONCLUSTERED (c1)
);
GO
INSERT dbo.Example
    (c1, c2)
VALUES
    (1, NULL);
GO
DECLARE @c2 integer = NULL;

-- Returns one row but should not
SELECT
    E.* 
FROM dbo.Example AS E 
    WITH (INDEX(IX))
WHERE
    E.c2 = @c2;
```

Any of the following will avoid the bug:

- Moving rows out of the delta store using any method including reorganizing with the compress rowgroups option specified
- Writing the predicate to explicitly reject `= NULL`
- Enabling undocumented trace flag 9130 to avoid pushing the predicate into the lookup

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=ca45c468fe94d0fddf3d1b2923882c7a) demo.

---

This bug was **fixed** in CU15 for SQL Server 2017 (and CU7 for SQL Server 2016 SP2):

[FIX: Query against table with both clustered columnstore index and nonclustered rowstore index may return incorrect results in SQL Server 2016 and 2017](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4497225/fix-query-against-table-with-both-clustered-columnstore-index-and-nonc)

Answer (score 8):

This is a bug with SQL Server. If a column is deleted from a table with a clustered columnstore index, and then a new column is added with the same name, it appears to be using the old, deleted column for the predicate. Here is the MVCE:

This script starts off with `10000` rows with `statusId` of `1` and `statusId2` of `5` - then drops the `statusID` column and renames `statusId2` to `statusId`. So at the end all rows should have a `statusId` of 5.

But the following query  hits the non clustered index...

```
select *
from example
where statusId = 1
    and total <= @filter
    and barcode = @barcode
    and id2 = @id2
```

... and returns `2` rows (with the selected `statusId` different from implied by the `WHERE` clause)...

```
+-------+---------+------+-------+----------+
|  id   | barcode | id2  | total | statusId |
+-------+---------+------+-------+----------+
|     5 |    5    | NULL |  5.00 |        5 |
| 10005 |    5    | NULL |  5.00 |        5 |
+-------+---------+------+-------+----------+
```

... whereas this one accesses the columnstore and correctly returns `0`

```
select count(*) 
from example 
where statusId = 1
```

---

**MVCE**

```
/*Create table with clustered columnstore and non clustered rowstore*/
CREATE TABLE example
(
id        INT IDENTITY(1, 1),
barcode   CHAR(22),
id2       INT,
total     DECIMAL(10,2),
statusId  TINYINT,
statusId2 TINYINT,
INDEX cci_example CLUSTERED COLUMNSTORE,
INDEX ix_example (barcode, total)
);

/* Insert 10000 rows all with (statusId,statusId2) = (1,5) */
INSERT example
       (barcode,
        id2,
        total,
        statusId,
        statusId2)
SELECT TOP (10000) barcode = row_number() OVER (ORDER BY @@spid),
                   id2 = NULL,
                   total = row_number() OVER (ORDER BY @@spid),
                   statusId = 1,
                   statusId2 = 5
FROM   sys.all_columns c1, sys.all_columns c2;

ALTER TABLE example
  DROP COLUMN statusid
/* Now have 10000 rows with statusId2 = 5 */


EXEC sys.sp_rename
  @objname = N'dbo.example.statusId2',
  @newname = 'statusId',
  @objtype = 'COLUMN';
/* Now have 10000 rows with StatusID = 5 */

INSERT example
       (barcode,
        id2,
        total,
        statusId)
SELECT TOP (10000) barcode = row_number() OVER (ORDER BY @@spid),
                   id2 = NULL,
                   total = row_number() OVER (ORDER BY @@spid),
                   statusId = 5
FROM   sys.all_columns c1, sys.all_columns c2;
/* Now have 20000 rows with StatusID = 5 */


DECLARE @filter  DECIMAL = 5,
        @barcode CHAR(22) = '5',
        @id2     INT = NULL; 

/*This returns 2 rows from the NCI*/
SELECT *
FROM   example WITH (INDEX = ix_example)
WHERE  statusId = 1
       AND total <= @filter
       AND barcode = @barcode
       AND id2 = @id2;

/*This counts 0 rows from the Columnstore*/
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM   example
WHERE  statusId = 1;
```

I have also [raised an issue on Azure feedback portal](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/37044220-columnstore-index-incorrectly-returning-data-from):

And for anyone else who encounters this, rebuilding the Clustered Columnstore Index fixes the problem:

```
alter index cci_example on example rebuild
```

Rebuilding the CCI only fixes any existing data. If new records are added, the issue arises again on these records; so currently the only known fix for the table is to recreate it entirely.

Comment: Not just the issue that it is using the old one for the predicate. The other strange thing is that it completely breaks the residual predicate on different columns `and id2 = @id2` should guarantee zero rows anyway as `@id2` is `null` but you still get the 2

Comment: RE: Your edit 2 does `REORGANIZE WITH (COMPRESS_ALL_ROW_GROUPS = ON);` do the job? That will clear the deltastore - does the issue still occur for new rows added subsequent to that?

Comment: Nope, seems to be the exact same outcome sadly?

Answer (score -4):

Based on the plans, it appears that the Columnstore index was created with SET ANSI_NULLS OFF.  Tables and indexes retain the setting as it was when the index was created. You can check by creating a duplicate Columnstore index while ensuring that ANSI_NULLS is ON, then either dropping the original or disabling it.

But, unless you have discovered a SQL Server bug, this is the only way that the results could happen.

Comment: Are you sure that 1) non-filtered indexes can maintain ANSI_NULLS settings separate from the base table, and 2) that the session ANSI_NULLS setting can actually cause discrepancies when the table is created with ANSI_NULLS OFF?

Comment: I did think this, but when I script out the definition of the CCI it has no set options, and if I create it with SET ANSI_NULLS ON before the index definition the result is the same?